# what will be the method to pass information to another target of intent class in androiod

Tags: android, android-intent

Which method of the Intent class allows you to pass information to the target? the answer must be putExtra(); but this is not the right answer.

Comment: Are you asking a question or stating a fact.. am confused here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
putExtra
```

not

```
putExtra();
```